# Outputting script output values from jenkins to a file

Tags: jenkins

I have my jenkins pipeline working and calling Ps scripts.

```
    env.output= powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '.\\scripts\\script.ps1 -target_servername')
```

I would like to save the env.output to an automatically generated file within the workspace directory.

```
    so like %workspace%\logs\%jobname%_%job_no%.log
```

And I would like to append details onto the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are alreaddy using powershell. So i think the Add-Content Commandlet is the perfect tool for your. Just switch to a multiline powershell script.

Comment: Hi. 

Thanks for the reply, because I am using powershell remoting. I do not want to write logs to the remote server, I prefer to write logs onto the jenkins server within the workspace directory.

Comment: you could write you output into a powershell variable, then use add-content and then use archive artifacts to tranfer the logfile from the jenkins client to the server.

Comment: Since i can echo the info that I want on jenkins, is it not possible to ouput that all within jenkins ?